# @Autowired in Spring PermissionEvaluator

Tags: spring, spring-security, spring-aop, spring-boot

First off I have googled this extensively and while it appears that there is supposedly a fix in place I cannot successfully reference an injected `@Bean` inside of a `PermissionEvaluator`:

https://jira.springsource.org/browse/SEC-2136?page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels:all-tabpanel

In that issue's comments section Rob Winch provides a work around suggestion

> to work around this issue, you can proxy your permissionEvaluator using LazyInitTargetSource

That being said, I am having trouble implementing the annotation-based JavaConfig version of the posted XML. **I am using Spring Boot 1.0.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT and spring-boot-starter-security.**

I have a class to configure method security as follows:

```
@Configuration
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true)
public class MethodSecurityConfig extends GlobalMethodSecurityConfiguration {                   

    @Override
    protected MethodSecurityExpressionHandler createExpressionHandler() {

        DefaultMethodSecurityExpressionHandler expressionHandler = new DefaultMethodSecurityExpressionHandler();
        expressionHandler.setPermissionEvaluator(new MyPermissionEvaluator());
        expressionHandler.setParameterNameDiscoverer(new SimpleParameterDiscoverer());

        return expressionHandler;
    }
}
```

And the start of a `PermissionEvaluator`:

```
public class MyPermissionEvaluator implements PermissionEvaluator {

    private static final Logger LOG = LoggerFactory.getLogger(MyPermissionEvaluator.class); 

    @Autowired
    private UserRepository userRepo;    

    @Override
    public boolean hasPermission(Authentication authentication, Object targetDomainObject, Object permission) {     

    if (authentication == null || !authentication.isAuthenticated()) {
        return false;
    }

    if (permission instanceof String) {

        switch((String) permission) {

        case "findUser":
            return handleUserPermission(authentication, targetDomainObject);

        default:
            LOG.error("No permission handler found for permission: " + permission);             
        }           
    }

    return false;
}

@Override
public boolean hasPermission(Authentication authentication, Serializable targetId, String targetType, Object permission) {

    throw new RuntimeException("Id-based permission evaluation not currently supported.");
}

private boolean handleUserPermission(Authentication auth, Object targetDomainObject) {

    if (targetDomainObject instanceof Long) {           

        boolean hasPermission = userRepo.canFind((Long) targetDomainObject);

        return hasPermission;
    }

    return false;
}

}
```

What needs to be done so that I can get a reference to my `UserRepository` from inside the `PremissionEvaluator`? I've attempted various workarounds w/ no success. It seems that nothing can be `@Autowired` into the `PermissionEvaluator`...

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Nothing can be autowired into an object that is created with `new ...()` (unless you are using `@Configurable` and AspectJ). So you almost certainly need to pull your `PermissionEvaluator` out into a `@Bean`. If you need to make it a lazy proxy as well (because of the ordering sensitivity of Spring Security initialization), then you should add `@Lazy @Scope(proxyMode=INTERFACES)` (or `TARGET_CLASS` if that suits you better).

Comment: That makes quite a bit of sense. I'll work on modifying the code this morning and post back! Thanks!

Comment: Hi Dave Syer, I got the same issue. Can you explain more about how to config in java annotation about " you almost certainly need to pull your PermissionEvaluator out into a @Bean" and "because of the ordering sensitivity of Spring Security initialization", thanks

Answer (score 12):

I had the same issue and the answer from Dave Syer worked perfectly for me.  To respond to the comment from jasonfungsing, to pull the PermissionEvaluator into a Bean I annotated my custom class with @Component and @Autowired the DAO into it:

```
@Component
public class CustomPermissionEvaluator implements PermissionEvaluator{

private CustomRepository customRepository;

@Autowired
public void setCustomRepository(CustomRepository customRepository) {
    this.customRepository = customRepository;
}

@Override
public boolean hasPermission(Authentication authentication, Object target, Object permission) {

    if (target instanceof ...
```

Then in my GlobalMethodSecurityConfiguration overriding class I created a private instance variable of my PermissionEvaluator class, @Autowired the PermissionEvaluator into it and used this instance in my setPermissionEvaluator method call (thus avoiding a "new" call):

```
@Configuration
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(securedEnabled = true, prePostEnabled = true)
public class MethodSecurityConfig extends GlobalMethodSecurityConfiguration{

private DataSource datasource;
private CustomPermissionEvaluator customPermissionEvaluator;

@Autowired
public void setCustomPermissionEvaluator(CustomPermissionEvaluator customPermissionEvaluator) {
    this.customPermissionEvaluator = customPermissionEvaluator;
}    
@Override
protected MethodSecurityExpressionHandler createExpressionHandler() {
    DefaultMethodSecurityExpressionHandler expressionHandler = new DefaultMethodSecurityExpressionHandler();
    expressionHandler.setPermissionEvaluator(customPermissionEvaluator);
    return expressionHandler;
}
```

I did not need to use the @LAZY or @SCOPE annotations.

Answer (score 2):

### For future users:

As per @Dave Syer suggestion issue was using **new** keyword changing  new MyPermissionEvaluator() to @Autowired will solve the issue as shown below.

changing below code

**From:**

```
@Configuration
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true)
public class MethodSecurityConfig extends GlobalMethodSecurityConfiguration {                   

    @Override
    protected MethodSecurityExpressionHandler createExpressionHandler() {

        DefaultMethodSecurityExpressionHandler expressionHandler = new DefaultMethodSecurityExpressionHandler();
        expressionHandler.setPermissionEvaluator(new MyPermissionEvaluator());
        expressionHandler.setParameterNameDiscoverer(new SimpleParameterDiscoverer());

        return expressionHandler;
    }
}
```

**To:**

```
@Configuration
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true)
public class MethodSecurityConfig extends GlobalMethodSecurityConfiguration { 

 @Autowired
 private MyPermissionEvaluator myPermissionEvaluator;

    @Override
    protected MethodSecurityExpressionHandler createExpressionHandler() {

        DefaultMethodSecurityExpressionHandler expressionHandler = new DefaultMethodSecurityExpressionHandler();
        expressionHandler.setPermissionEvaluator(myPermissionEvaluator);
        expressionHandler.setParameterNameDiscoverer(new SimpleParameterDiscoverer());

        return expressionHandler;
    }
}
```

with the above change below code will start working as expected.

```
@Autowired
    private UserRepository userRepo;
```

Comment: Just to add, you still need to annotate your evaluator class with `@Component`

Answer (score 0):

Solutions from Dave Syer & SchonWieder works for me. As alternative I want to show, how I solved this problem before. I inject Permision Evaluator in MethodSecurityConfig like anonymous class.

```js
@Configuration
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true)
public class MethodSecurityConfig extends GlobalMethodSecurityConfiguration{

    @Autowired DataSource dataSource;

    @Override    
    protected MethodSecurityExpressionHandler createExpressionHandler() {
       DefaultMethodSecurityExpressionHandler expressionHandler = new DefaultMethodSecurityExpressionHandler();
       expressionHandler.setPermissionEvaluator(new PermissionEvaluator(){

            @Override
            public boolean hasPermission(Authentication auth, Object targetDomainObject, Object permission) {
                    
                    JdbcTemplate template = new JdbcTemplate(dataSource);
                    ... 
                    if (count==1){
                        return true;
                    } else {
                        return false;            
                    }
                }

            @Override
            public boolean hasPermission(Authentication arg0, Serializable arg1, String arg2, Object arg3) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    return false;
                }
                
            });
            return expressionHandler;
        }
}
```